# Laravel route post error I've tried everything

Tags: laravel

Hello guys I've got problem with laravel post.. and I need your help I'll send you some pictures

[Laravel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoJ9l.png)[My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpIqk.png)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'nazev'=>'required',
        'popis'=>'required',
        'obtiznost'=>'required'
    ]);

    $race = new competition;
    $race->name = $request->input('nazev');
    $race->descrption = $request->input('popis');
    $race->difficulty = $request->input('obtiznost');
    $race->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $race->save();

    return view('race.body');
}
```

Comment: Show your routes and what error you are getting?

Comment: Show us your `route.php` file.

Comment: Here https://imgur.com/a/FukmH46

Comment: check your route method, it must be post

Answer (score 4):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('races.store') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is on the form action attribute, it also could be `action="{{ action('RacesController@store') }}"`

Comment: Thanks man it works but i don't know the differences between  {{ route('races.store') }}

Comment: @PatrikZendeli both are same.

Comment: @PatrikZendeli your version is totally wrong. What namelivia say in comment is same as I say.

Answer (score 0):

put `{{ csrf_field() }}` after opening the form